# How to get share counts from Twitter

Tags: twitter, count, share

Since 20 November, its' not possible to get Twitter share counts in this way:

> http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=

Is there alternative to do that or it's not possible? Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to get them from Twitter. There may be some 3rd party sites springing up - but they won't be accurate.

Comment: In their official statement, it was written that we can use Twitter API to get them. But is it paid or is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://opensharecount.com, it provides a drop-in replacement for that URL.  Only downside is it only can 'see' tweets from up to seven days ago, but it will include those in future counts so it is a good way to get approximate counts for your new posts.